# Services generated by openapi-generator-cli not injectable

Tags: angular, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate an API client from a v2 swagger file with openapi-generator-cli. For this I am using the docker container of openapi-generator-cli, which reports its version as '4.1.0-SNAPSHOT'.

Code generation works with the following options:

```json
{
    "npmName": "...",
    "npmVersion": "0.0.3",
    "snapshot": true,
    "ngVersion": "8.1.1"
}
```

and I have also tried to set the `providedInRoot` option to true.

However, the generated service classes are not annotated with the `@Injectable` decorator. So after importing them in my component and adding the service in the constructor of the component, I am not able to use them. This is how my component looks like:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UsersService, User } from '...'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(userService: UsersService) {}

  title = 'user-frontend';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.listUsers();
  }

}
```

which fails, because userService does not exist in the scope of AppComponent.

This is how I import the generated module:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ApiModule } from '...';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ApiModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas on where my error is when generating the api client?

**EDIT:**
The generated code looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

    protected basePath = 'http://localhost';
    public defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    public configuration = new Configuration();
    public encoder: HttpParameterCodec;

    constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string, @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {

        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.configuration.basePath = configuration.basePath || basePath || this.basePath;

        } else {
            this.configuration.basePath = basePath || this.basePath;
        }
        this.encoder = this.configuration.encoder || new CustomHttpParameterCodec();
    }

...
}
```

Comment: Have you try to put `ApiModule` in providers array?

Comment: @AugustinR, I just tried that, but it did not help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alot of questions import { ApiModule } from '...'; where is code generated come from ?
You publish it to npm and consume it or just copy paste the generated code?
Try this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ApiModule.forRoot(() => {
      return new Configuration({
        basePath: `${environment.HOST}:${environment.PORT}`,
      });
    }),,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Your generated code should like this

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PetsService {

    protected basePath = 'http://localhost';
    public defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    public configuration = new Configuration();

    constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string, @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {

        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.configuration.basePath = configuration.basePath || basePath || this.basePath;

        } else {
            this.configuration.basePath = basePath || this.basePath;
        }
    }
```

Solution : use private or public in the constructor

Explanation:
Here we have the same as your problem typescript dont know what you want

```
class TestClass {
  constructor(name: string) {
  }
}
```

Here we have last example in a normal POO promamming language

```
class TestClass {
  private name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

But typescript give us a easy way to minimize the code

```
class TestClass {
  constructor(private name: string) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately I still get the same error. To answer your question, I publish the generated code to a private npm und consume it from there. Since I can import the ApiModule, classes and so on, I am quite confident that this part works. Could you hint at why the different ways of bringing the ApiModule into my project could lead to such an error?

Comment: You generate the code and convert it to a angular library with ng-packagr?

Comment: Exactly, I generate the code, switch to the folder with the generated code, then I run: ```npm``` install, next ```npm run build``` (which executes ng-packagr), then I log in to my npm registry and do a ```npm publish dist``` to my registry.

Comment: I got the same so seems like is a template issue check my edit above and tell me if you generate code its something like that

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my question and appended the exported UsersService class. Looks the same for me.

Comment: its weird, after work I will help you more. There are some error or just not recognize the service ?

Comment: With the code above I get the following error when building the angular project: Property 'userService' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

Comment: try private userService: UsersService

Comment: Thanks, I also just tried that, and now it works... Do you have an explanation why a private/public keyword is necessary? Is there no defaulting to private for example?

Comment: the explanation is above :)