# Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used

Tags: angular, nestjs, swagger-codegen, ngrx-effects

The setup:

1. MongoDB (Atlas or local)
2. Backend:  NestJS, OAS, using swagger-codegen to package 'backend client' for...
3. Angular 15 + Material Design + Ngrx (store + effects)

Recently I added the state manage work using Ngrx and when I add the EffectsModule I get this error:

> Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.

Issue began when adding EffectsModule to import (line 36) of [app.module.ts](https://github.com/abcox/toybox-web-ng2/blob/ngrx-state/src/app/app.module.ts)

I continue my research of this, and would appreciate any thoughts or insights. Based on [this SO article (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212072/angular-upgrade-error-inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context-at-in) the error appears generic. I am open to ideas of how to chase this down.

Repo branches necessary to replicate environment:

1. [Angular client](https://github.com/abcox/toybox-web-ng2/tree/ngrx-state)
2. [Backend API](https://github.com/abcox/toybox-api)

Other SO articles I have come across:

1. [Angular upgrade - Error: inject() must be called from an injection context at injectInjectorOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212072/angular-upgrade-error-inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context-at-in)
2. [inject() must be called from an injection context when using angular library in ionic project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685286/inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context-when-using-angular-library-in)

> Causes error to change to: NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!

3. [Services generated by openapi-generator-cli not injectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266369/services-generated-by-openapi-generator-cli-not-injectable)

LATEST:

I suspected that the typescript being generated by the [openapitools/openapi-generator-cli](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation) is no longer sufficient whilst including the ngrx work. I did find the [typescript-angular](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-angular) generator in the [list of generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators) and will give this a try...

Comment: As you link above mentioned: It seems that the modules that you want to use, is not compatible with you angular version. Try it with an other / compatible version.
Ensure that ngcc is runnning when starting your app the first time after installing the npm module.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was likely a few things.  Specifically, setting up the module correctly.  [This article](https://www.kevinboosten.dev/how-i-use-an-openapi-spec-in-my-angular-projects) was useful in pointing out that I had not setup and referenced the API package correctly.

Specifically the part under heading "Usage example" where code shows like:

```
import { PostsService } from './core/api/v1';
```

Therefore, I change the path to my output arg when running the openapi-generator. Instead of using `npm link` I referenced the output directly.

Comment: Note to self:  When generating the module from `openapi-generator-cli`, make sure to output to a folder under the `\src` or expect NG0203 error thrown by build deployed to the environment (i.e. Azure Web App).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in the Chrome console logs. I had an angular library I created and imported it into an existing angular app. I was using `npm install C:/...dist/myapp` to install the library.

My app was missing in the angular.json:
`projects/myapp/architect/build/options/preserveSymlinks: true`

After changing preserveSymlinks to true, reinstalling, I no longer had the mentioned error.

Comment: You are my hero of the day. I've been trying to solve the problem for 3 hours. Your answer has saved me at least 3 more

Answer (score 0):

```
// Import your router with inject function :
const router = inject(Router) ;
```